# How to apply union string type in Mongoose/Monogo schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The matchType can only be "football" or "basketball", is there any schema type in Mongoose can represent it?

```js
const EventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matchType: {
    type: "football" | "basketball",
    require: true,
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Link to the documentation : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators

You may need to use something like that :

```js
const EventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matchType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["football", "basketball"], 
    require: true,
  })
```